# Работа с файлом с++

Tags: c++

Я создал файл и записал в него информацию с помощью показанного кода, и сделал вывод этой информации. Кто-то может подсказать, как сделать сортировку (например, по имени) в этом файле, чтобы, когда я выберу в меню "Сортировка по имени", были эти строки выведены в консоль упорядоченными? КОД:

```
ofstream fout("strings.txt", ios::trunc);
fout << "Football Maksim 2006 Maryana 0985632134 400" << endl;
fout << "Voleyball Anton 2004 Andriy 0975623785 250" << endl;
fout << "Basketball Sasha 2005 Lida 0662735285 350"<< endl;
fout.close();

ifstream fs("strings.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);

    if (!fs)
    {
        cout << "File not opened!" << endl;
        return menu(); 
    }

    for (int r = 0; r < strings; r++)
    {
        fs.getline(mass[r], len - 1, ch);
        cout << "String " << r + 1 << " = " << mass[r] << endl; 
    }
    fs.close(); 
    return menu();
```

Comment: Прямо в файле - никак. Читайте файл в память и сортируйте там.

Answer (score 1):

Что бы отсортировать, нужно строки вначале куда то сохранить. Потом, отсортировать и вывести.

```
for (int r = 0; r < strings; r++)
{
    fs.getline(mass[r], len - 1, ch);
}
fs.close();
```

теперь можно отсортировать

```
std::sort(mass, mass+strings);
```

они будут отсортированы в алфавитном порядке. Если нужно как то более сложно, то нужно будет написать функцию или лямбду для этого конкретного сравнения.

Например, если хочется отсортировать по длине строки, то это будет так

```
std::sort(mass, mass+strings,[](const std::string& a, const std::string&  b) -> bool {return a.size() < b.size();});
```

Теперь, можно вывести

```
for (int r = 0; r < strings; r++)
{
   cout << "String " << r + 1 << " = " << mass[r] << endl; 
}
```

В коде я надеюсь, что strings содержит корректное кол-во строк mass и сам массив mass правильно создан. Но я бы использовал `std::vector<std::string>`